# Redirect user and always ensure full page load/reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

If I am on the page `http://mywebsite.com/contact` and I do:

```
window.location.assign('http://mywebsite.com/contact#foo');
```

The page doesn't refresh and I understand thats desired. But I want to refresh/reload the page (to update the users cache). Is there a Javascript or JQuery function that I can use that will change the url and always reload/refresh the page?

**Usecase**
When a user clicks any `anchor` html element, my function checks if the page has been reloaded/loaded within the last 24 hours. If it hasn't I will call my javascript function above to ensure the user navigates to their desired page but also reloads the whole page to ensure they are working with the latest version of the Single Page Application.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `window.location.reload(true);` after `window.location.assign()`

Comment: that works on Chrome but not on IE11 or Firefox. They first go to the new page then reload back to the prev page.

Comment: And what about location.replace?

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.reload(true)` will reload the page from the server.
`window.location.reload(false)` will reload from cache, if available.